# Why the error `Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read` if I'm re-assigning res.json?

Tags: graphql, fetch, graphql-request, automatic-persisted-queries

I'm trying to use [the code I found here](https://github.com/jasonkuhrt/graphql-request/issues/269) for APQ (automatic persisted queries) and [graphql-request](https://github.com/jasonkuhrt/graphql-request).

But if I use the code like described:

```
export const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient("http://localhost:3000", {
    fetch: createPersistedQueryFetch(fetch),
});
```

I'm getting this error in browser's console:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read
    at getResult (index.ts:639:48)
    at makeRequest (index.ts:394:24)
    at async Object.queryFn (utils.ts:84:25)
```

I think this is the issue:

```
export const createPersistedQueryFetch =
  (fetchImpl: Fetch): Fetch =>
  async (info, init) => {
    // ...

    // send a request without the query
    const res = await fetchImpl(
      requestWithoutQuery.info,
      requestWithoutQuery.init
    );
    const body = await res.json();

    // if the query was not found in the server, send another request with the query
    if (isPersistedQueryNotFoundError(body)) {
      return fetchImpl(requestWithQueryHash.info, requestWithQueryHash.init);
    } else {
      res.json = () => Promise.resolve(body);
      return res;
    }
  };
```

`graphql-request` is trying to re-read the body already read in `createPersistedQueryFetch` function.

Why is the re-assignment to `res.json` (with `res.json = () => Promise.resolve(body)`) not working?